# .Net Core 3.1 SignalR Authorize using client certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, certificate, authorization, signalr

Hello I have problem with SignalR(.Net Core 3.1(client and server) (ASP server))

**Problem:** I try to make authorization using certificates which server generated(PowerShell generated certificate .pfx).

**Explaining idea:** client makes http request to server with login, server checks user data and if all correct returns certificate which is used in HubConnectionBuilder.

**Part where I get stuck:** problem is I googled as much as I could and I found I need to create custom authorization handler which validates client certificate, but I never done that, examples I found is using .Net Framework which some libs don't work on .Net core.

**Soo far on google found:** I found I need to create authorization handler which validates client certificate I can safely use Authorize attribute, worst part is Microsoft tutorials does not show validation part on server only how set certificate on client and I kind of lost, thanks for lighting me up. :)

**Solution I try to achieve and I need help with it:** I try to make authorization handler which validates client certificate. But lack knowledge from where to begin

**It would help:** If anyone could provide url where I could find working example or something that would give me good start.

Comment: Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1) seems to cover that

Comment: @Evk How does it validate certificate that is signed using server certificate? I was unable to find where I provide server certificate as base.